# How do I output a vertical histogram?

Tags: c, output, histogram

I have a string array containing the names of 10 countries (max length of 100). I have another array containing the corresponding total amount that country won. The two arrays look like this:

```c
char countryNames[10][100] = {"Japan", "USA", "China", "ROC", "UK", "Australia", 
                              "Kosova", "Italy", "France", "Canada"}

int totalMedals[10] = {13, 14, 18, 12, 7, 6, 2, 9, 5, 4}
```

So Japan won 13 medals, USA won 14 medals, ... etc. I'm having trouble finding a way to output these statistics in a vertical histogram using *'s. This is the output I am looking for:

[image: Histogram Example Output]

I can't find a solution to this that isn't extremely hard coded. There is no specific spacing but I want it to look mostly like the example.
Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Like anything else, you have to know what the tallest output will be before you start printing and you have to determine what column each of `countryNames` will use. Then you know your histogram will require  that many (e.g. `18`) rows to display. You then loop from `0` to `18` to output the histogram (or you can loop from `18` to `0`) Then just check each country in the order they are displayed and output a value when the row index includes that histogram column -- at that countries offset from the beginning of the line. (which is why you have to check/output in order)

Comment: If you used pen and paper, how would you do it then? Perhaps finding out the the highest "total medals" might be a good start?

Comment: And you know that a `for` loop can loop in either direction, not only from `0` to `18` but also just as easy from `18` to `0`? Such a counting-down loop could be very useful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You output a vertical histogram by outputting one line after the other.
I.e. you have to drop the whole "vertical" idea and force everything into lines, by a generous amount of foresight.

Basically:
Step 1: Find `pad`, the length of the longest name.
Step 2: Find `total`, the total number of entries.
Step 3: Create a newline-and-zero-terminated character sequence of `pad * total` blanks.
Step 4: Find `index`, the index of the highest number.
Step 5: Change the blank at position `index * pad` to `'*'`.
Step 6: Find `next`, the index of the next highest number.
Step 7: Output the character sequence `totalMedals[index]-totalMedals[next]` times.
Step 8: Copy the value of `next` into `index`.
Step 9: Repeat from step 5 until you are done, using 0 as an additional last number.

Then you only need to output the names with padding according to preference.

This is simplified by the assumption of unique numbers of medals, i.e. no two have the same number - as in your input data. (Though I suspect it might actually also work for non-unique numbers.)

Comment: This is intentionally according to the compromise described in  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (in short: "help with homework, but don't just do it for askers" ). For obvious reasons. I think I am even doing some 3 to 5 helping steps at once, feeling generous.

Comment: After you have attempted to write your code to match the guidance you were given, if you are stuck on a particular part of the problem, edit you question and ADD the code you have written at the end of your question (indented by 4-spaces, or with a `\`\`\`` above and below so your code formats properly) and indicate what part you are stuck on. Then additional help will be provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
int max_medals = 0;
int total_countries = totalMedals.length; //this is 10 here

// here we are finding how many max medals have been won, this will 
// allow us to find the height of the matrix

for (int i=0; i<total_countries; i++)
    max_medals = max(totalMedals[i], max_mexdals);

// create the matrix representing histogram
char matrix[total_countries][max_medals];

// traversing left to right, bottom to up, if that country 
// has 'j+1' number of medals, fill the matrix else let it be blank
for(int j=0; j<max_medals; j++)
   for(int i =0; i<total_countries; i++)
      if(totalMedals[i] <= j+1)
         matrix[i][j] = '*'
      else
         matrix[i][j] = ' '
```

Confirm the syntax and edge cases once, hope this helps!